# CSS before with a transition

Tags: css, css-transitions

I want a transition on a wordpress menu item. 
I plan to insert an icon before on hover...

Now I test this with a word and this works fine...

```css
.academy .avia-menu-text:hover::before {
    content:'Jetzt ';
   transition:all 3s;
-webkit-transition:all 3s;
}
```

But the transition is not working. I need it with a smooth fade in. [testfile](https://test.fukuru.de/test.html)

Comment: What do you want to transition actually? "fade in" implies changing the opacity, so perhaps you are looking for `.avia-menu-text::before {opacity:0}` and  `.avia-menu-text:hover::before {opacity:1}`.

Comment: `im very new on stackoverflow. Dont throw stones on my for this question.` --> avoid such sentence and you won't get any stones, you simply need to ask a clear question

Comment: You would need to define the before pseudo element first with the icon and transition and on hover, set the transition properties. In your current code, it does not show any transitions. You should do some research on how transition works first. Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions

Comment: @TemaniAfif Haha :)

Answer (score 0):

If I´m understanding your question correctly you want an annimated text before your element.

You can add this element without the hover state:

```
.academy .avia-menu-text:before {
    width: 0; 
    transition: 3s;
    content: 'your text'; 
}
.academy .avia-menu-text:hover:before {
    width: 100%; 
}
```

Here is a small example I made in a container

```css
p:before{ content: 'hello world';  width: 0; display: block; overflow: hidden;  transition: .3s; position: absolute; left: -100px; top: 0; white-space: nowrap;}
p:hover:before{ width: 100%; }
div{ width: 300px; height: 100px; }
p{ position: relative; left: 100px; }
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Text here</p>   
</div>
```